# Cast exception error

Tags: java, oop, casting

I decided to simulate this example code from `Android` app:

`TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_display_message);`

`findViewById` returns `View` object and then we cast it to a `TextView` one(`TextView` is a subclass of `View`)

It seems I have misunderstood how it works. I was expecting this code to work because `C extends B` and therefore I should downcast a `B` object to `C`.

But I am getting an exception at runtime that I can't cast `B` to `C`.

So can anyone explain where I am wrong? And why the `Android` sample works?

```
public class A{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        B b = new B();
        b.f();
        C c = (C)b;
    }
}

class B{
    public void f(){
        System.out.println("Class B");
    }
}

class C extends B{
    public void f(){
        System.out.println("Class C");
    }
}
```

Comment: A cast will fail if the *execution-time type* of the object doesn't match the type you're trying to cast to. In your case it doesn't, because you're creating an instance of `B`. In the Android case, presumably the object involved is *actually* a `TextView`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: study polymorphic statements and follow above comment

Answer (score 2):

Cast operation lets you change the static type of your object, which is another way of saying "tell the compiler what you know about the type of the object being cast."

If you have a variable of type `B` which contains an object of type `C`, you are allowed to cast that variable to `C`:

```
B b = new C();
C c = (C)b; // works fine
```

This is allowed precisely because `b`'s object is actually a `C`.

When the object referenced by `b` is *not* a `C`, the compiler will catch your mistake, and throw a cast exception:

```
B b = new B();
C c = (C)b; // throws class cast exception
```

The difference between a successful and unsuccessful is decided by the actual type of the object at runtime. The code that works manages to cast a `View` to `TextView` because the variable which is statically typed  as `View` actually references a `TextView` at runtime.

Comment: Are you saying that while `findViewById` is being executed, it understands that the desired view is actually a `TextView` and does something like `return (TextView) the_view_found_by_id`?

Comment: @CuriousGuy When `LayoutInflater` inflates layout from xml file it actually sees that you defined `<TextView ... />` tag and instantiates `android.widget.TextView` class. That's why class should be cast to the same class which is defined in xml.

Comment: @AndriiAbramov if `findViewById` returns a `TextView` then why should I explicitly cast it like that `TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id)`?

Comment: @CuriousGuy it is made for flexibility. `View` represents the basic building block for user interface components. Because xml file is loaded and parsed during runtime, java by that moment is already compiled.

Comment: @CuriousGuy The object returned by `findViewById` happens to have runtime type of `TextView`, but that's only for the specific ID that you supplied. However, the compiler has no idea that the ID that you supplied would yield a `TextView`, because the return type of the method is `View`. You are the only one who knows it's actually `TextView`. That's why you need to tell the compiler that it's a `TextView` by adding a cast.

Answer (score 2):

**In java,** you cannot assign a `superclass reference variable` to a `subclass reference variable` without a cast of the `subclass type`. Examples can find in When is an explicit object reference casting is required?. The compiler is happy when you explict cast the superclass reference to subclass reference, but the compiler does not care what the actual object holded by the reference. Does it actually have a superclass object, or just a superclass reference holding a subclass object? No answer from compile time but it has to answer this quesiton.

*You can not just take a parent object and suddenly turn it into a child though. The parent object is not an instance of the subclass. If the actual object holded by the reference is a superclass object, casting it to a subclass reference result in a compile time error.*

**In your case `B is parent class` and `C is its child`.**

```
class SuperClass {
  // ...
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
  // ...
}

public class Program {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // case 1: actual SuperClass object

    SuperClass p1 = new SuperClass();

    // case 2: SubClass object is referred by a SuperClass reference 

    SuperClass p2 = new SubClass();

    SubClass s1 = (SubClass) p1; //run time error
    SubClass s2 = (SubClass) p2; //OK
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android `findViewById`returns instance of  `View` Class. Which is a direct superclass of `TextView` and other view elements.
So if you want to replicate something like that, then you can do something like this:

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        A a = new A();
        C c = (C)a.getViewByid('c');

        c.f();
    }

}

class A {

    public B getViewByid(char c) {

        B b = null;
        switch (c) {

        case 'b':
            b = new B();
            break;

        case 'c':
            b = new C();
            break;

        default:
            b = new B();
        }

        return b;
    }
}

class B {
    public void f() {
        System.out.println("Class B");
    }

}

class C extends B {
    public void f() {    
        System.out.println("Class C");
    }

}
```